# $\overline{U}\cap V\subseteq\overline{U\cap V}$

Tags: general-topology

In particular if the equality is generally false, is it true if $V$ is open?

Could someone help, me please?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Indeed we only have $U\subseteq\overline{U}\rightarrow U\cap V\subseteq\overline{U}\cap V$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $V$ is open, this holds: let $x \in \overline{U} \cap V$, so $x \in V$ and $x \in \overline{U}$.

Then let $O$ be an arbitrary open subset containing $x$. Then $x \in O \cap V$ and this set is also open, so it intersects $U$ as $x \in \overline{U}$. So $$\emptyset \neq (V \cap O) \cap U = O\cap (U \cap V)$$ for any open neighbourhood $O$ of $x$, which implies $x \in \overline{U \cap V}$, as required.

Answer (score 3):

In general this is false:

Consider $U := [0,1)$ and $V:= [1,2]$. The we have $\overline{U} = [0,1]$ and thus $\overline{U} \cap V = \{1\}$ but $U \cap V = \emptyset$ and thus their closure is empty as well.

However, if $V$ is open, this is true.